# Solution to replace InfoPath Form for SharePoint submission

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, css, html

I need to replace an InfoPath form that has multiple repeating tables and repeating date fields, has the ability to create revisions while keeping older version data. We dont have access to microsoft forms, powerapps or other cool tools since I work on a Military base. I would like to keep it simple using HTML-CSS-JS but if needed can put it in sql. I think its too much We have over 2000 forms to include half of those are modifications - not sure if HTML is the best solution. I dont have a lot of coding experience but am a fast learner. :)

Answer (score 0):

Below three points will give you some basic idea on where to start:

- You can make use of ***Angular JS with Bootstrap*** and embed those to "Content Editor Webpart" using classic SharePoint page.
- else make use of **Angular with PNPJS**
- use **SPFX**